# How long does PhD Application Process take in the UK?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I submitted my application with a supervisor's name fora UK university last week. I plan to apply for a scbolarship after getting an offer. The scholarship application deadline is in March. I would like to know how long it takes to get an application result in a UK uni?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the university. You should tell them your situation.

Comment: To the OP: And work on your spelling. :-)

Comment: Indeed, the decision process is usually very complex.  There are many applicants from the UK, the EU and elsewhere with many different constraints, many different possible sources of funding, different potential supervisors who may or may not be waiting to see what other applications might appear, and so on.  No sensible prediction is possible without asking the university in question.

Answer (score 1):

Most PhD students in the UK will be looking for some sort of scholarship, often directly from the university. Universities will therefore base decisions around what funding they can get confirmation for. If you're applying elsewhere for funding, and you need to have a confirmed offer before applying, I would talk to whoever you submitted the application to, as they could probably make a decision on an unfunded place in time if needed, but won't necessarily do so without a reason to.